# XML output to text file?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to output a specific node to output to a text file(output to console fine) but I keep getting an error message: 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' to 'string[]' on this line:

```
string[] lines = elemList;
```

Here is some more code:

```
namespace countC
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("list.xml");

            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("version");
            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(elemList[i].InnerXml);
                string[] lines = elemList;
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\VBtest\STIGapp.txt", lines);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to assign an object of type `XmlNodeList` to a variable of type `string[]` - the two are incompatible and you can't assign one from the other.

If you do this instead then it will at least compile:

```
string line = elemList[i].InnerXml;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\VBtest\STIGapp.txt", line);
```

Although I'm not sure that it will do what you want (if `elemList` contains more that one element the above will keep overwriting the given file).

Comment: Ok cool that works. The weird thing is that the text file doesn't save the the loops.

Comment: @nhat It might be that the `InnerXml` property is an empty string, which would happen if the element was empty. Check the value of `line` in the debugger.

Comment: ah ok double checking the data, it only saves the last loop.

Comment: @nhat Thats because `WriteAllText` overwrites the existing file, and so each loop the file is overwritten.

Comment: So after an hour of searching on google and found a topic on how to not have stuff get overwritten, I found a method AppendAllText.

Answer (score 1):

elemList is an XmlNodeList, you can't implicitly cast it to a string array.

You could try this

```
string line = elemList[i].InnerText;
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\VBtest\STIGapp.txt", line);
```

but this of course, depends on your data.

Comment: Hi Russ, I tried that but I get an error message: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

I did try that option before but unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Oh Sorry, WriteAllLines should probably be changed to WriteLine